# Getting s3 objects with Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have been using aws-sdk gem with Rails, for uploading and downloading objects. I believe it's working fine.

Demo code:

```
begin

s3 = AWS::S3.new
bucket = s3.buckets[ENV['BUCKET_NAME']]
bucket.objects.create(fname, data)
object = bucket.objects[fname]
exported_url   =  object.url_for(:get, {expires: 3.weeks,
             response_content_type: "text/csv", response_content_disposition: 
"attachment; filename=#{fname}.csv"}).to_s
rescue Aws::S3::Errors::ServiceError => e
 puts e.message
end
```

Are there any issues if uploading a large file to `s3`? I mean, that issues will affect my code. Will it handle that situation for large files? Should I go for the multipart options in `s3`?

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues you should watch out for:

1. This will block the current thread while it's running. For a large file, this could be a substantial amount of time. You should consider moving this code out to a Sidekiq (or similar) worker, so that you aren't blocking threads in your web app.
2. When you rescue exceptions, you just `puts` them, which you're likely to ignore in production. You should be logging that exception to a place that you can get ahold of it later. I would personally just not rescue it and use BugSnag or similar in my application to ensure that errors are collected and kept for resolution.